# AJAX loading iFrame again and again

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iframe

I have iFrameA and iFrameB to display data. I have AJAX code which will get ID from mySQL and display video according to the ID. AJAX will check the code in every to seconds. Suppose I have ID 1 for video A to display in iFrameA and ID 2 for video B to display in iFrameB. If someone enter 1 in the database then video A will be displayed until ID 2 is entered. But AJAX will continue its task in every second.

I am trying the code bellow but in every second the iFrame is reloading. I want if video A is displaying no one enter ID 2 then video 2 will be display continue without reloading.

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title> View</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        function values(){
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET", 
               url: "task.php",
               success: function(data){
                  $('div#myFrame').html(data);
               }
           });
       };
       setInterval(values, 1000);
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a>
    <div id="myFrame">
    <?php

    include "task.php";  
    ?>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php



//connect database and find

        switch ($ID) {
            case 1:
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<iframe src="../video/index.php" id="imgiframe"></iframe>';
                    echo '</div>';                          
                break;
                case 2:     
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<iframe src="../video/index.php" id="imgiframe"></iframe>';
                    echo '</div>';
                break;                    
                default:
                    echo "NO VIDEO";
                break;
            }  
?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything that runs every second. `setTimeout` just runs once, did you mean `setInterval`? And your `case` syntax is wrong, it should be `case 1:` and `case 2:`.

Comment: yup setInterval, and its fix now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the data you receive is the same as the previous time, then you don't change anything.

```
$(function(){
    var lastData = '';
    function values(){
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET", 
           url: "task.php",
           success: function(data){
                if (data != lastData) {
                    $('div#myFrame').html(data);
                    lastData = data;
                }
           }
       });
   };
   setInterval(values, 1000);
});
```

Comment: cool, I was looking for exactly this code !, since I m new so. thanks anyways

Comment: hi Barmar, can you please look on the link and give me a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912331/how-to-manage-ajax-code-to-display-image-and-video-using-switch-case-on-html