# how to manage ajax code to display image and video using switch case on HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have 2 tables(image and video).
In my HTML code I have three buttons, named slide_image, video, ans single_image. Here I use iframe to load image and video, I am in a single page I can see video/image.
so when I will click in slide_image button it will show image one by one in a web page, and when I click video it display video. up to this is ok but when I click single_image button it doesn't display anything, because of the iframe ans switch case. I want when I clcik single_image button, it only display 3rd image.

I am using the AJAX to check and load the page only I get new data. but my image table is only one and I load data in iframe.
Note that; I can't refresh the page until I get net content, for example now I its displaying video but when only slide_image button clicked then new page will load in iframe.
I think I need to modify AJAX code or in the case statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title> View</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var lastData = '';
    function values(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "task.php",
            success: function(data){
                if (data != lastData) {
                    $('div#myFrame').html(data);
                    lastData = data;
                }
            }
        });
    };
    setInterval(values, 5000);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a>
    <div id="myFrame">
    <?php

    include "task.php";  
    ?>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**task.php**

```
<?php    

//connect database and find

switch ($ID) {
case 1:
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<iframe src="../image/index.php" id="imgiframe"></iframe>';
    echo '</div>';                          
    break;
case 2:     
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<iframe src="../video/index.php" id="imgiframe"></iframe>';
    echo '</div>';
    break;                    
default:
    echo "NO VIDEO";
    break;
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... that is actually really hard to read.. Only because I don't think you fully understand what your ajax is doing. Which in reality is confusing at first until you read everything and do it a couple of times...

So... data is going to be something like "NO VIDEO" and never be == lastData ... data is the RETURN from success...

However... we can have some fun with this.. You can start with a single ID..

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var lastData = 0; // set your data to 0 as that is the real original

    values(); // Go ahead and call the function on initialization so you can see it instantly.
    function values(){
      lastData += 1 // always increment by 1 if it is always one. You may need to fit this better for your situation.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // You had GET 
        url: "task.php",
        data: {ID: lastData}, // You did not have this
        success: function(data){
          $('#myFrame').html(data);
          // if you have a better way to return lastData then do that here, but you will need to use json to get a better splitting of data.
        }
      });

   }
   setInterval(values, 5000);
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This should give you a better realization as to what is happening. You have to send data to actually read and then when you are in your PHP document you would use `$_REQUEST['ID']` and do what you will with it.

Look up ajax and json encoding and get more familiar with the layout and how you should do this.

Honestly I wouldn't approach video / image slide show this way. I would use `<img src="...">` and replace the source or do something very similar with the HTML5 `<video>` tag as it would handle most of my needs. I'm not sure if it will yours.

So yea.. Try something along those lines and hopefully it helps you..

*This is by no means a full solution. I do not have a full project overview to get you to the final and the use of iframes does not make sense to me. I did not touch on that for a reason.*